# Karate test - how to embed html in Cucumber HTML report?

Tags: html, cucumber, karate

e.g. display a link or display a table in the html report

I tried 'print' but it is not working (e.g. the link is displayed as a plain text string, not a link)

Answer (score 2):

The latest version 0.9.0 supports this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-embed

Refer to this example: [`embed.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/embed/embed.feature)

```
* eval karate.embed('<h1>Hello World</h1>', 'text/html')
```

Comment: * def embedUrl =
"""
function(url, hyperlinkText){
    var html = '<a href="' + url + '" > + hyperlinkText +'</a>';
    karate.embed(html,'text/html');
} 
"""